# vb.net xml de-serialization

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have the following XML and for the life of me I can't figure out what the deserialized class would look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
    <AL>
       <AcctName>Test</AcctName>
       <RetentionCodes>
           <RetentionCode Del="N">ZZZZZ</RetentionCode>
           <RetentionCode Del="N">XXXXX</RetentionCode>
       </RetentionCodes>
    </AL>
</Root>
```

So far I have this for a class:

```vb
<Serializable(), XmlRoot("Root")>
Public Class clsRecord Inherits clsFunctions(Of clsRecord)

Private m_AL As clsAL = Nothing
 <XmlElement("AL")>
 Public Property AL() As clsAL
    Get
        Return m_AL
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As clsAL)
        m_AL = value
    End Set
 End Property

 Public Sub New()
 End Sub

 End Class

Public Class clsAL Inherits clsFunctions(Of clsAL)

 Private m_AcctName As String = String.Empty
 Public Property AcctName() As String
    Get
        Return m_AcctName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_AcctName = value.ToString
    End Set
 End Property

<XmlArrayItem("RetentionCode")>
Public Property RetentionCodes As List(Of String)

End Class
```

I can get the Node values but I'm not sure how to get the DEL attribute into the class short of making a separate RetentionCode class.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Steve Sirica, for years we have been getting away from the old fashion prefix for variables and class names like you have them. Just name them without the prefix and you have better readability.

Comment: Yes, RetentionCode would be a class as `DEL` would be a property. The XML here would be referring to a property on the main class that is a `List(Of RetentionCode)` hence multiple entries.

Comment: I ended up changing direction.  I ended up making it it's own object with 3 elements.  Canned the use of an attribute.  All is working.  All is good.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RetentionCode must be a class. Make a list of RetentionCode using `<XmlArrayItem("RetentionCode")>`.

```vb
<XmlRoot("Root")>
Public Class clsRecord Inherits clsFunctions(Of clsRecord)
    Private m_AL As clsAL = Nothing
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property AL() As clsAL
        Get
            Return m_AL
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As clsAL)
            m_AL = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class clsAL Inherits clsFunctions(Of clsAL)
    Private m_AcctName As String = String.Empty
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property AcctName() As String
        Get
            Return m_AcctName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_AcctName = value.ToString
        End Set
    End Property
    <XmlArrayItem("RetentionCode")>
    Public Property RetentionCodes As List(Of RetentionCode)
End Class

Public Class RetentionCode
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Del As String
    <XmlTextAttribute>
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```